# I want to build a video game app for android and ios, but I'm worried about where to start

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, qt, game-physics

I tried researching these topics but I'm a little bit torn on where to start.

1: my native language is c++ so i looked into using Qt, but I'm worried I wont be able to implement stuff like the android keyboard or the iOS game center that uses achievements and in store app purchases, etc.

2: I want it to be a 2D game with a scrolling background that uses touch and drag controls (kind of like angry birds), achievements, leaderboards, in store purchases, and be able to make it free with ad support.

3: I read a few iOS programming books my friend had so I know objective C also.

4: I could probably pick up java easily.

5: I read a bit about javascript programming but didnt do any programming in it.

6: I watched some Qt tutorials but none of them seemed to cover game development.

So if I make it in Qt will I still be able to use the elements described above?(game center etc.)

If I make it in objective C on a virtual machine will I be able to port it over to android in any possible way?

And what is/are a good tutorial to get me started learning how to make a game like this with these kind of elements in it? (whether it be in Qt or something better)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know where to start, I would strongly recommend going native in either iOS or Android.  Make the game perform well on either one, and you can have a successful app.  So many people try to make something generic that works across platforms, and end up with something really mediocre or worse.

If your game is a success, then it will make it to the other platforms either by you or someone else getting to work on those.

Comment: can you further explain what is meant by "someone else getting to work on those" ? and what would you recomend starting with, android or iOS? my phone is android, computer is windows, and my only ipod touch is the extremely old one with a rounded back, and I'm kind of poor, but I did read a lot about iphone programming.

Comment: What I meant is, that once someone makes a successful game, they get people to port it to other platforms.  Not just ios and android.  I think that you should really focus on making a really good game that works for your platform.  Given what you have, it would take a few grand to make a decent dev system for iOS, so I'd start with Android.  I would recommend you start with a simple "throwaway" game that just scrolls, animates 2d objects, and plays sounds.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to invest in this, I might direct you to check out the Unity engine which has support for Android among other devices.

I mention this because you bring up porting over the game from iOS or to iOS. The Unity engine supports multiple platforms, and will make your life easier if you end up trying to deploy your game across all mobile platforms.

It has a free version to try out if you are interested. The android and ios plugins however will cost you more.

http://unity3d.com/

Answer (score 2):

Qt for android has the software keyboard functionality. I recommend you start with Qt 5.1 or necessitas (for android). The game center might be accessible using objective-c++.

Comment: what is objective-c++ ??? Is it a new language I've never heard of? Or a typo?

Comment: Objective-C++ is a combination of Objective C & C++. It lets you call Objective C methods AND use C++ objects. It's especially useful as glue when you're dealing with native facilities like Game Center and also need to use C++ libraries.

Comment: so how would you combine Qt and objective C++? would you make half of the game in Qt Creator and the other half in Xcode? how would you combine the final product?

Comment: XCode is just an IDE, just as Qt Creator. You can use both, or none and compile from the command line and edit with `ed`.

Comment: i honestly thought it was a typo xD Well, I guess I learned something... :D

Comment: so how would I combine the main game with the added game center tools? do I need some kind of tutorial for this?

Comment: You would do a similar thing as you would with a pure ObjC app. You can mix C++ and ObjC freely.

Comment: so are you saying I could put objective C tools mixed into my Qt game in Qt Creator?

Comment: @JL_: yes, this is what you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Cocos2d-X. It's a C++ port of Cocos 2D that supports iOS, Android, Windows Phone, and several other platforms. We used it at Bionic Panda Games with good results.

Comment: so are you saying this is a port of the iphone SDK for use on any of these platforms? what IDE do I have to use it in if I have to pick one? Is this the same kind of thing as Qt where I just use these libraries in a certain IDE and convert the binaries before submitting to each platform?

Comment: Cocos2d is its own framework similar to QT but optimized for game development. Many popular iOS games, including everything from Zynga (who now own it) were developed with it.